# shared user accounts across workstations

Tags: remote-desktop, user-management

I run a small academic research group and we have 4 workstations and one server, all running Ubuntu. I would like to have login credentials that are shared across all workstations and the server, so I can issue a userid once, and the user could sit down at any workstation and login. Nominally, the filesystem would be shared so that the user could have their files/desktop environment at any workstation. Is there any way to set up such a environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying all of the required steps on Ask Ubuntu would be cumbersome, so only the installation commands are given below...

For further reading on configuring the Lightweight Directory Access Protocol, head to the [Official Ubuntu LDAP documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html)

```
sudo apt-get install slapd ldap-utils
```

Did I mention to **read the documentation first?** ;-)